# Textview on top of Imageview works in 2.x but Text disappears in ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to do something like this:
[image]

For some reason the ImageView is not shown when I change my targetSdk to 14.  Anyone know what is going on?

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/venueinformation_header_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="Venue Information Header"
    android:src="@drawable/venueinformation_header_image" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/venueinformation_header_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/venuinformation_header_label"
    android:textSize="55sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Something was wrong with the image itself.  I think it was just too large.  I made it smaller and it worked.

Comment: You could keep the same image and scale it in the app. Should mean it will display well on any size screen then. Think the property is scaletype

Comment: Smaller in scale, or smaller in weight/size? Just curious where the restriction may be. Thanks.

Comment: i had the same problem - the image was just too big. not sure if it's an excess of bytes or pixels that it doesn't like, but reducing the size of my photo worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a custom view extends the imageview on the paint method, draw the text you wish or whatever you need
2. Keep your layout, instead of ReleativeLayout, you should use a framelayout in order to be able to to put the textview on top of the imageview

Comment: How did this work in 2.x though?  I tried putting both elements in a framelayout as a child of the relative layout and that didn't work.  I have other stuff that I didn't include in the code I posted that I dont want to move around in a frame layout.